# SQL: How to filter by column with a Union

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm very new to SQl so I'm not sure how to frame my question for a google search.. Basically, I'm trying to UNION two sets of columns. They have very similar information; Set A is a series of products with a column for the vendor. Set B is a series of products without a vendor.

What I want to do is filter set A such that only a certain vendor's products are show (Which is what I did with a WHERE clause). But then, I want to union Set A and Set B such that the values in Set B will will only display (and combine) where there is an entry in Set A for the product.

That is, to explain better, I want Set B to 'look at' Set A. It will see that Set A only has items from a certain vendor and Set B will then remove items that Set A does not have (items that are NOT from that vendor).

Any thoughts? Thank you,

Code below:

```
SELECT ([Transfer_From]
      ,'Transfer_To' = [WAREHOUSE_CODE]
      ,'Product_Number' = [PRODUCT_NUMBER]
      ,'QTY_Trans' = [quantity_received]
      ,'Transfer_Date' = [received_date]

  FROM [fstrkdb_1].[dbo].[Inventry]
  WHERE vendor_number = '1074'

UNION

SELECT [Transfer_From]
        ,[Transfer_To]
      ,[Product_Number]
      ,'QTY_Trans' =[Quantity_Allocated]
      ,[Transfer_Date]

  FROM [fstrkdb_1].[dbo].[InvtransFromWhs]


ORDER BY Transfer_Date

GO
```

Comment: What RDBMS is this (looks to be SQL Server based on the [] use)  This could be possible though a Common table expression using a join.

Comment: Can you give some sample data and expected output?

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use `EXISTS` in the `WHERE` clause.  A CTE helps avoid repeating the first query:

```
WITH a as (
      SELECT Transfer_From, WAREHOUSE_CODE as Transfer_To, Product_Number,
             quantity_received as QTY_Trans, received_date as Transfer_Date
      FROM [fstrkdb_1].[dbo].[Inventry]
      WHERE vendor_number = '1074'
     )
SELECT a.*
FROM a
UNION ALL
SELECT Transfer_From, Transfer_To, Product_Number, Quantity_Allocated
       Transfer_Date
FROM [fstrkdb_1].[dbo].InvtransFromWhs ifw
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM a WHERE a.Product_Number = ifw.Product_Number)
ORDER BY Transfer_Date;
```

You only need `UNION` if you are expecting duplicates.  The queries should not be creating unexpected duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH DataSet1 as (
SELECT ([Transfer_From]
      ,'Transfer_To' = [WAREHOUSE_CODE]
      ,'Product_Number' = [PRODUCT_NUMBER]
      ,'QTY_Trans' = [quantity_received]
      ,'Transfer_Date' = [received_date]

  FROM [fstrkdb_1].[dbo].[Inventry]
  WHERE vendor_number = '1074'),
DataSet2 as (

SELECT [Transfer_From]
        ,[Transfer_To]
      ,[Product_Number]
      ,'QTY_Trans' =[Quantity_Allocated]
      ,[Transfer_Date]

  FROM [fstrkdb_1].[dbo].[InvtransFromWhs] A
  INNER JOIN dataset1 B
   on A.Product_number = B.Product_number)

SELECT * FROM dataset1
UNION 
SELECT * FROM dataset2
ORDER BY Transfer_Date
```

What this would do is generate dataset1.  then use the products from dataset1 as a filter on dataset2 and then union those two sets together.

Comment: This looks pretty inefficient to me.  Presumably, a product could be repeated multiple times in `DataSet1` and then the `UNION` incurs extra overhead for removing the duplicates.

Comment: I would hope different vendors would have different product numbers, but an exists and union all could be more efficient.  not enough is know about the data to be certain however.

Comment: yeah probably better off using `WHERE A.Product_number IN (SELECT Product_number from DataSet1)`

Comment: Ug no. I'd use the join or exists over that.  I would only use in if I knew the records in dataset 1 would always be under 50.

Comment: lol.. personally i'd use temp tables over CTEs in the case as well